# Autologin on UbuntuStudio 21.04

Tags: plasma, ubuntu-studio, 21.04

After installing Ubuntu Studio 21.04 I've noticed that the autologin it's not working. I checked on system settings but couldn't find any option there.

Comment: Autologin should be avoid, say the "best practices" book. The time you save by not typing ONE password is lost later, several times, when the keyring need unlocking, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run

```
sudo vim.tiny /etc/sddm.conf
```

and change `Session=Ubuntu` to `Session=plasma`.

Answer (score 1):

I think I didn't look hard enough on settings.

1. System Settings > Startup and Shutdown > Login Screen (SDDM)
2. Select the SDDM
3. Select the "Behavior" button that's on the bottom of the window.
4. Check on Automatically log in as user and select your user
5. Apply

NOTE: I didn't check the answer given by yq-ysy // Kulfy

Comment: Thank you! It was driving me nuts! I need to autologin, because the `numlock` is not  enabled at login time and I'm **sick** of activating it manually each time I log in.